# How to SSH from Cloud Functions to a GCE Instance

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-functions, google-compute-engine

How to execute command through SSH to GCE Instance from a Cloud Function?

Answer (score 1):

You need:

- GCE instance.
- Serverless VPC Connector in same region and network.
- Enable OS Login for GCE instance or for all project.
- Create a Cloud Functions same region and network.

Steps:

1. Create instance in zone europe-west3-c network default
2. Create VPC Serverless Connector in same zone, same network.
3. Create Cloud Function with Python, with the code listed.
4. In Runtime, Build and Connections Settings > Connections, add the VPC Connector created in step 2.
5. I enabled the OS Login project wise, however you may want to allow it for only one instance.

```
gcloud compute project-info add-metadata \
    --metadata enable-oslogin=TRUE
```

6. Run the cloud function.

Cloud Function code, from [samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/ea52a4f74e78e75f59905f65c029de15b0621d27/compute/oslogin):

```py
import argparse
import logging
import subprocess
import time
import uuid

import googleapiclient.discovery
import requests


# Global variables
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_METADATA_URL = (
    'http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/'
    'service-accounts/default/email')
HEADERS = {'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google'}

# [END imports_and_variables]


# [START run_command_local]
def execute(cmd, cwd=None, capture_output=False, env=None, raise_errors=True):
    """Execute an external command (wrapper for Python subprocess)."""
    logging.info('Executing command: {cmd}'.format(cmd=str(cmd)))
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE if capture_output else None
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, cwd=cwd, env=env, stdout=stdout)
    output = process.communicate()[0]
    returncode = process.returncode
    if returncode:
        # Error
        if raise_errors:
            raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(returncode, cmd)
        else:
            logging.info('Command returned error status %s', returncode)
    if output:
        logging.info(output)
    return returncode, output
# [END run_command_local]


# [START create_key]
def create_ssh_key(oslogin, account, private_key_file=None, expire_time=300):
    """Generate an SSH key pair and apply it to the specified account."""
    private_key_file = private_key_file or '/tmp/key-' + str(uuid.uuid4())
    execute(['ssh-keygen', '-t', 'rsa', '-N', '', '-f', private_key_file])

    with open(private_key_file + '.pub', 'r') as original:
        public_key = original.read().strip()

    # Expiration time is in microseconds.
    expiration = int((time.time() + expire_time) * 1000000)

    body = {
        'key': public_key,
        'expirationTimeUsec': expiration,
    }
    oslogin.users().importSshPublicKey(parent=account, body=body).execute()
    return private_key_file
# [END create_key]


# [START run_command_remote]
def run_ssh(cmd, private_key_file, username, hostname):
    """Run a command on a remote system."""
    ssh_command = [
        'ssh', '-i', private_key_file, '-o', 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no',
        '{username}@{hostname}'.format(username=username, hostname=hostname),
        cmd,
    ]
    ssh = subprocess.Popen(
        ssh_command, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    result = ssh.stdout.readlines()
    return result if result else ssh.stderr.readlines()

# [END run_command_remote]


# [START main]
def main(cmd, project, instance=None, zone=None,
         oslogin=None, account=None, hostname=None, username=None):
    """Run a command on a remote system."""

    # Create the OS Login API object.
    oslogin = oslogin or googleapiclient.discovery.build('oslogin', 'v1')

    # Identify the service account ID if it is not already provided.
    account = account or requests.get(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_METADATA_URL, headers=HEADERS).text
    if not account.startswith('users/'):
        account = 'users/' + account

    # Create a new SSH key pair and associate it with the service account.
    private_key_file = create_ssh_key(oslogin, account)

    # Using the OS Login API, get the POSIX user name from the login profile
    # for the service account.
    profile = oslogin.users().getLoginProfile(name=account).execute()
    username = username or profile.get('posixAccounts')[0].get('username')

    # Create the hostname of the target instance using the instance name,
    # the zone where the instance is located, and the project that owns the
    # instance.
    hostname = hostname or '{instance}.{zone}.c.{project}.internal'.format(
        instance=instance, zone=zone, project=project)

    # Run a command on the remote instance over SSH.
    result = run_ssh(cmd, private_key_file, username, hostname)

    # Print the command line output from the remote instance.
    # Use .rstrip() rather than end='' for Python 2 compatability.
    for line in result:
        print(line.decode('utf-8').rstrip('\n\r'))

    # Shred the private key and delete the pair.
    execute(['shred', private_key_file])
    execute(['rm', private_key_file])
    execute(['rm', private_key_file + '.pub'])

def hello_world(request):
    main("ls -la", YOUR_PROJECT_NAME, hostname=GCE_INSTANCE_PRIVATE_IP)
    return 'done'
```

Requirements.txt

```
google-api-python-client==2.6.0
google-auth==1.30.1
google-auth-httplib2==0.1.0
requests==2.25.1
```

Comment: Have you actually verified that this code executes correctly on Cloud Function?

Comment: yes I did, the function main prints the contents of the filesystem in the logs, which can be found in Cloud Logging or in the logs in the Cloud Function. Are you getting any error?

Comment: When i trying it it says sa_number@instance_ip: Permission denied (publickey). I did all the steps, is it still working or did google disabled it?

Comment: My cloud function with `ssh` doesn't work anymore because ```ssh: not found```